# xaml wpf using resource in the same xaml file

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

I am working with xaml resources as follows:

```
<local:MyUIElement x:Key="MyUI" />


<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyControl}" x:Key="MyXC">
    <Grid>
      ........
      ........
      <MyUI />


    </Grid>
```

Can I do something like this? Using the resource "MyUI" directly inside other resource in the same xaml file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Key is just an *attribute* of an *object element*. Just as Content is an attribute of Button. So you can't use <MyUI> instead use <local:MyUIElement>

Resources are stored as dictionaries and keys are used to identify the objects within them.
So in code you could do something like this, to say, change control template on a button click.

obj = this.Resources["MyXC"] as ControlTemplate;